# PG::ConnectionBad Rails and PostgreSQL on development MacOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I've used rails with SQlite and MySQL. First time using PostgreSQL. Just installed PostgreSQL on my local machine. Using Heroku for Production.

Every time I run rake **db:migrate** or **rake db:create** I get the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I installed PostgreSQL with Homebrew, but never setup a user or password.
Here's my Postgres setup:

```
Daves-MBP-2:project dave$ ps aux | grep postgres 
postgres           670   0.0  0.0  2466764   1816   ??  S    Fri10AM   0:00.33 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdflagwriter
postgres           658   0.0  0.0  2514516   3032   ??  S    Fri10AM   0:01.31 /usr/sbin/distnoted agent
postgres           657   0.0  0.0  2542724   6336   ??  S    Fri10AM   0:05.69 /usr/libexec/trustd --agent
postgres           656   0.0  0.0  2545304   6676   ??  S    Fri10AM   0:04.28 /usr/libexec/lsd
postgres           655   0.0  0.0  2515008   2596   ??  S    Fri10AM   0:00.07 /usr/sbin/cfprefsd agent
postgres           240   0.0  0.0  2508940    920   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:01.06 postgres: stats collector process    
postgres           239   0.0  0.0  2653940   1860   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:00.64 postgres: autovacuum launcher process    
postgres           238   0.0  0.0  2653940    832   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:01.00 postgres: wal writer process    
postgres           237   0.0  0.0  2653940    900   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:01.02 postgres: writer process    
postgres           236   0.0  0.0  2653940    896   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:00.04 postgres: checkpointer process    
postgres           233   0.0  0.0  2508940    728   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:00.00 postgres: logger process    
postgres           108   0.0  0.0  2654196   3372   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:00.32 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data
dave             68244   0.0  0.0  2442020   2012 s000  S+    4:28PM   0:00.00 grep postgres
```

Here is my database.yml file

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: "mydatabase"


# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  url: "HEROKU URL"
```

Here are the settings on pg_hba.conf, which I got from
- cd /usr/local/var/postgres/
- open pg_hba.conf
[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here are the contents from the comments below:

First file "com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.6.plist":

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.6</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/postmaster</string>
                <string>-D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>postgres</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
         <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
         <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Second File "homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.postgresql</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres</string>
    <string>-D</string>
    <string>/usr/local/var/postgres</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf` in an editor. Make sure the values for USER and METHOD match below sample (**all** and **trust**).

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Save the file and then run `pg_ctl reload -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data` from the terminal.

Comment: I verified the pg_hba.conf has those settings. When I run the command to reload I get this error: "pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied"

Comment: It looks like Postgres was started by another user in your log. How did you start Postgres after installing it through Homebrew?

Comment: From my project folder: "brew services start postgresql"

Comment: It seems that brew is starting the service under a user called "postgres" which is not what you are logged in under. Try to add "username: postgres" to the database.yml file in your application under development. Let me know if you still get the same error.

Comment: Yep, that worked...Thank You. (I also needed a password). How do I change the the default user Brew is starting it with?

Comment: Try to run the command `/usr/bin/stat -f '%Su'` and let me know what the output is from that. It's odd that your brew services start from a different username but when I run postgresql using brew services it defaults to my logged in user.

Comment: Output from /usr/bin/stat -f '%Su' is "dave"

Comment: Okay, let's try another two things. We are looking for a file called homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist

1. Run `sudo ls /Library/LaunchDaemons/` and check if it is there.
2. Run `ls ~/Library/LaunchAgents/` and check if it is there.

Comment: The first command returned: `com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.6.plist`. The second command returned: `homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

Comment: Can your copy and paste the content from each file?

Comment: Change the launchd.postgresql file in LaunchDaemons and add _bkup to it and remove the plist extension for now.  And try to start brew services postgresql again.